# Первичный или уникальный?

Tags: mysql

ip уникальный или первичный ключ?

```
CREATE TABLE `ban` (
`ip` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`dt` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

ip не должен повторяться. Что правильно.

Comment: А кто, простите, для IP выделяет 255 varchar`a??? Это для протокола IPv130???

И его (ip) вроде как лучше целым хранить - INET_ATON и INET_NTOA в помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уж очень большой разницы нет. Всё зависит от того, как вы собираетесь пользоваться данной таблицей. Поле с первичным ключом не может быть NULL и используется для однозначной идентификации записи, в то время как **unique** может содержать NULL и записей таких может быть много. Если очень схематически и двумя словами:

> PRIMARY KEY == UNIQUE + NOT NULL , и
> PRIMARY KEY может быть только один.